# How to set footer to be on the bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my footer to be at the bottom of any screen, not only small ones.

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
 <footer class="footer-distributed">

  <div class="footer-left">

    <p class="footer-links">
      <a href="index.html">Početna</a>
      ·
      <a href="pages/rs/onama.html">O Nama</a>
      ·
      <a href="pages/rs/reference.html">Reference</a>
      ·
      <a href="pages/rs/usluge.html">Usluge</a>
      ·
      <a href="pages/rs/galerija.html">Galerija</a>
      ·
      <a href="pages/rs/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    </p>

    <p class="footer-company-name">Copyright © <script>
                        document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
                    </script> ddd </p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-center">

    <div>
      <a href=""/><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      <p><span></span></p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
      <p></p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="mailto:"/><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      <p><a href="mailto:" style="color:white;"></a></p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer-right">

  </div>

</footer>

Here is the css:



    '.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #292c2f;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;

    padding: 5px 50px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 40%;
}

/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  #5383d3;
}

/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Footer Center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #5383d3;
    text-decoration: none;;
}


/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 20%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

'

How can I keep the footer on the bottom of the screen, independent from content in the body?

Comment: why dont you put a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is called a sticky footer. Look here for a great tutorial. I use this all of the time: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

You want to set something like the following in your css:

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}
```